# Admin SDK for multiple google apps accounts

Tags: google-admin-sdk

My team is trying to develop a product for the google apps marketplace and I am having issues with the workflow in the new ADMIN SDK.

With the now deprecated Provisioning API we simply ask for a username and password from the account we are trying to manage.

With the ADMIN SDK it seems as though they would need to go enable the API, create a key and do a lot of manual work for this to happen.  This really is a tough option for us as the technical level of our clients is not likely to be able to make this transition.

Is there something like the work flow for the provisioning API where they can enable management from a third party or a recommended workflow for a developer to build an application that can access any number of google apps accounts?

A use case for this is say I want to develop a different option for a console, I want to build a console web app and simply ask for credentials or easy setup routine and allow our users to manage their google apps account in a different way.

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

The Admin SDK Directory and Reports APIs work correctly with 2-legged OAuth 1.0a which is what the Google Apps Marketplace currently supports and automates. You do need to turn the Admin SDK on under "Register for additional APIs" from your Vendor Profile page on the marketplace. Also, the [Administrative APIs](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60757) for the domain must be turned on. You'll get a generic error that the domain cannot use the APIs if it's off in which case you can direct the client to the exact CPanel page where they can turn it on.

Comment: Well that is handy.  We sell direct too is the marketplace required or can we do it without that step too?

Comment: Without the Marketplace I'd recommend doing regular 3-legged OAuth 2.0. That way nothing other than approving access is necessary for the admin. You could do 2-legged OAuth 1.0a or the new OAuth 2.0 Service Accounts but that would require the admins to manually authorize your client ID in their control panel which is an error-prone process.